# npm link, not install, package.json dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I  want to local link all the explicit dependencies stated in my `package.json`.

If I just try  `npm link` what I get is a local install of all of the packages, independently of whether or not they are already globally installed.

I didn't expect that. What I expected, and what I needed, is a behavior similar as if I'd do a `npm link package`. I wanted `npm link` to inspect the dependencies in `package.json` and for each of the, to create the link, and do a global install if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some months of waiting, I've come out with my own implementation, that I am posting here for the record.

I have two small scripts

one `packageDependencies.js` that extracts all dependencies from a `package.json`. Sschematically the code has:

```
fs.readFile(process.argv[2]||'package.json','utf8',(err,data)=>{
  if(err) return console.error(err);
  var o = JSON.parse(data);
  for (var p in o.dependencies) console.log(p);
  for (var p in o.devDependencies) console.log(p);
});
```

and another `npmlink.sh` that iterates over that list and for each package, just `npm --global install` and `npm link`. Schematically,

```
for d in "$(node packageDependencies.js)"; do 
  npm --global install $d
  npm link $d
done
```

Comment: Very nice, I like your implementation! Thanks.

Comment: Hello is there any new feature to do it with npm link, since this post is >two years old?

Answer (score 7):

`npm link` isn't designed to work that way.  There are two ways to use it, and both depend on you downloading the dependency you want to link beforehand.

### First way (two steps)

`cd ../dependency
npm link 
cd ../project
npm link dependency`

### Second way (one step)

`cd project
npm link ../dependency`

I think what you're trying to do is `npm link` where the target is a globally installed package (as opposed to a globally installed link to some directory on your filesystem).  `npm` doesn't support that.

Ref: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Comment: too bad, thanks anyway. I have edited my question to clarify my requirements. I will wait for someone to come out with a solution. If not, I will accept your answer.

Comment: I agree, that npm link in target package is not updating dependencies in package.json, but people online do say that npm link updates..
Look for example on this article: https://medium.com/@alexishevia/the-magic-behind-npm-link-d94dcb3a81af
They clearly say that you need to use --no-save during unlink..
Im pretty sure I saw this behavior myself - when you `npm link dependency` in target folder package.json got new item in dependencies object.